# Android share text with link

Tags: android, android-intent

I have to share text with link.
'Share Text' is followed as.
"Please click this. snapchat://video?param1=text "

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
intent.setType("text/plain");
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, text);
context.startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Share"));

Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
intent.setType("text/html");
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, Html.html(text));
context.startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Share"));
```

All code showed link as general text. It is not acted on SMS or gmail app, etc.

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `android.content.Intent`.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
  intent.setType("text/plain");
  intent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, text);
  intent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT,"Title goes here")
  context.startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Share"));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
intent.setType("text/plain");

//This line for the link:


intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, text);


//This one for text suggestion:

intent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT,"Title goes here")
context.startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Share"));
```

Answer (score -1):

It will show as text only as it is not a valid link. Test the link once and try it.